# How To Transition object on RelativeLayout Using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want `Transition` my object called ball inside `ImageView` on `ReltiveLayout`  when I touch ReltiveLayout then ball move to center of point has been touch

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //ImageView.W(70dp) ImageView.H(70dp) to get center touch
    ImageView ball;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ball = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ball);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);



        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                //ImageView.W(70dp) ImageView.H(70dp)
               //touch X,Y-70 to move ball to center touch
              ball.setX(motionEvent.getX()-70);
              ball.setY(motionEvent.getY()-70);


                return false;
            }
        });


    }
}
```